# How can I update product price when quantity/number of items change?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a product listing and I need to develop a JavaScript code that will help change price with counter and I want to implement it on all the products I have using one JavaScript code

[image]

This is the HTML code

```
 <h3>Almonds</h3>

    <div class="price">
      <p>Price Per ticket : $<span id="ticket_price">7</span></p>
      <p>Subtotal : <b>$<span id="total">0</span></b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="quantity">
      <span>quantity : </span>
      <input type="number" id="num" oninput="calc()" min="1" max="1000" value="1" />
      <span> kg </span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn">add to cart</a>
  </div>
```

JavaScript code

```
    function calc() {
  var price = document.getElementById("ticket_price").innerHTML;
  var noTickets = document.getElementById("num").value;
  var total = parseFloat(price) * noTickets
  if (!isNaN(total))
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total
}
```

*The problem is the JavaScript code is only working for one product it is not working for other products of same id**

Comment: `id` should be unique across the document. see: [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getElementById()` is only for one element in the DOM, so it would only work for the first element I guess. Try to use a `class` or a unique `id` for any element, example:
`ticket_price_1`,
`ticket_price_2`,
`ticket_price_3`

---

If you want to use classes, remember that you are working with an array of DOM objects. So you will need to specified the index of the element you want to modified:

**This wouldn´t work**

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("itemprice");
```

**This should work**

```
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("itemprice")[0];  //look at the index [0]
```

- Each element of a class has an unique index, so you need to specify it in order to modified the element you want. The index of each element depends on the order of the elements in the HTML file.

Here an example of how to work with classes:

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");   // no index means get all elements with that class

console.log(elements[0].innerHTML);    // print content of first element in class (index [0])
```

```html
<div class="myclass">Hello</div>
<div class="myclass">world</div>
<div class="myclass">!!!!!</div>
```

---

- For you case, using classes, just changed the `id` to a `class`, and modified the `calc()` function to `calc(n)` where `n` is the product number:

```js
function calc(n) {
  var price = document.getElementsByClassName("ticket_price")[n].innerHTML;
  var noTickets = document.getElementsByClassName("num")[n].value;
  var total = parseFloat(price) * noTickets;
  if (!isNaN(total))
    document.getElementsByClassName("total")[n].innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<h3>Almonds</h3>
<div class="price">
  <p>Price Per ticket : $<span class="ticket_price">7</span></p>
  <p>Subtotal : <b>$<span class="total">0</span></b></p>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <span>quantity : </span>
  <input type="number" class="num" oninput="calc(0)" min="1" max="1000" value="1" />
  <span> kg </span>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn">add to cart</a>
</div>
<h3>Carrots</h3>
<div class="price">
  <p>Price Per ticket : $<span class="ticket_price">7</span></p>
  <p>Subtotal : <b>$<span class="total">0</span></b></p>
</div>
<div class="quantity">
  <span>quantity : </span>
  <input type="number" class="num" oninput="calc(1)" min="1" max="1000" value="1" />
  <span> kg </span>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn">add to cart</a>
</div>
```

Comment: i have used classes but it still doesn't work --> https://codepen.io/ibadhussain/pen/mdmwOpY

Comment: i understand it but how can i change the price of every product even with this i can change the price of only one product

Comment: Look now, I added classes and a product number to each product.